# Failed to parse remote port - vscode using ssh

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I get the following error trying to use vscode-remote using ssh.
I think this is related to escape codes.. but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
> Starting agent...
> Waiting for server log...
> [?1034h
>  
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
>  
> [?1034h
> 77cf6633-c4e9-44d4-93ab-d002229c03ef==36237==
> [?1034h
> [?1034h
"install" terminal command done
Received install output: [?1034h[?1034h
Failed to parse remote port from server output: [?1034h[?1034
```

The log file left on the server .vscode-remote directory indicates the server started fine:

```
IP Address: x.x.x.x
Extension host agent listening on xxxxx
```

Any help appreciated.